# Is there an easy-to-use, platform-independent package that we can use to read & write gzip streams under C++?

Tags: c++, linux, gzip

I would like to find some C++ packages that can function as what we have in the GZipStream Class [(MSDN Description)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) in .NET Framework. I'm using them under Linux.

And I'd be dealing with large files (possibly GB or even TB sizes) so the efficiency of the gzipstream implementation is also a concern.

What's your advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always use the original [ZLib library](http://www.zlib.net/).  It includes the functionality required to decompress gzip files.

Comment: Just curious, is there any performance comparison between zlib and gzipstream class under .net?

Comment: @derekhh Not that I know of - but GZipStream in the framework is awful (incredibly slow, and really poor on the compression side).  My personal feeling is that zlib is quite a bit faster, but that's subjective as I haven't measured it...

Comment: @derekhh If you're using .NET, there are much better alternatives than the framework, such as http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Comment: Nope, I'm trying to use it under Linux, but I'm also aware that GZipStream is not fast...so I'm trying to see if I can have a better alternative.

Comment: @derekhh the dotnetzip library works in mono, on linux ;)  zlib is pretty quick, and used by a LOT of libraries.  It works very well on linux and windows.